# Counting the least repeated value and printing the name of that person

Tags: sql

I have a database called employees and I want to write an SQL query where you count the least repeating office_id and get the persons name who sits in that office. I can't get it right, will I need to use a subquery for this or is it possible without subquerys? It seems so simple yet, I can't solve it.

| id | first_name | office_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Stan | 1 |
| 2 | Danny | 1 |
| 3 | Elle | 2 |

So here I would want to get the name Elle since she has the least reapted office id.
All I have so far is:

```
SELECT first_name, COUNT(office_id)
FROM employees 
GROUP BY first_name;
```

But all this does is return how many times each name appears in my table. Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Tag only the database that you use.

Comment: What would you want with 4 rows with two IDs each

Comment: What if you have 2 offices with only 1 person in?

Comment: Good point @Larnu, But this database won't be altered, so it doesn't matter. Only one office will have one person.

Comment: Which DBMS is this ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming working with mysql or Postgresql you can try this :

```
with cte as ( 
  SELECT office_id
  FROM employees 
  GROUP BY office_id
  order by count(1) asc
  limit 1
)
select e.* from cte c
inner join employees e on e.office_id = c.office_id
```

Using `with` will get the least repeating office then with inner join we get all the persons.

You can `limit 2` to get the two smallest offices ...

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/r8Ns5_8C)

Comment: With a small change (Because `limit` is unknown on sql-server) it works on sql-server too. see: https://dbfiddle.uk/xGfZ89am